# gradle dependency with classifier

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle version 4.6:

in dependencies I add this:

```
 testCompile "com.kuku:kuku:1.0:tests"
```

also tried this and same:

```
 testCompile  group: "com.kuku", name: "kuku", version: "1.0", classifier: "tests"
```

then gradle throw error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find kuku-tests.jar (project :serializer_v9).

what I am doing wrong? needless to say I see the kuku tests jar in the build directory

Comment: Have you tried this notation: `testCompile files("kuku-tests.jar")`, founded here in the gradle documentation: [Declaring Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#example_declaring_multiple_file_dependencies)

Comment: @Chocolord this will work in some cases when the kuku project is in my file system, but when it is not it will not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the problem is Gradle includeBuild does not support yet publication that does not default: [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/composite-build-with-test-sources/20244)

So the only way is to create separate jar with the test classes

UPDATE: [02/04/2023]

Seems like current Gradle version: 8.0.2 fixed that issue and it should be supported now.